# intersect a dictionary and a list to return another dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, functional-programming

**How do you pass in a list of headers and get back the key/value pairs?**

I've created a method like the following:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> GetHeaderValues(
    IReadOnlyList<string> keys, IHeaderDictionary headers)
{
}
```

I'd like to pass in a list of string such as `"trackingId, requestId, corrId"` and get back a dictionary like so:

```
trackingId: 123123
requestId: abc123123
corrId: xyz123
```

The purpose of this is to pass in ALL the headers, and retrieve only the desired headers.

**How do we intersect these two objects `IReadOnlyList` and `IHeaderDictionary` and `map` into a regular `IDictionary`?**

I've attempted to intersect the two with the following:

`headers.Keys.Intersect(keys);` however this will return an ienumerable string.

Comment: they're passed in the request from `req`:         `public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)`

Comment: Please [show any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: @HereticMonkey i've updated. let me know what additional information i can provide.

Comment: @HereticMonkey take note of Carlo's answer below. it might help you in the future

Comment: Sorry, how will that answer help me know what you've tried before?

Comment: @HereticMonkey please view the two answers below, if you're not familiar with the functional style of programming, this paradigm is gaining immense traction and will help you

Comment: Thanks. Reading [ask] may help you craft better questions in the future.

Comment: @HereticMonkey in fact, the answers below demonstrated to me that the question was crafted and asked productively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a short **pseudo-code** :

```
intersect(keys1,keys2)        // get common keys list
    |> map to (key,value)     // map to key-value pair list
    |> to dictionary           // convert list to dict
```

C# Implementation :

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> GetHeaderValues(IReadOnlyList<string> keys, IHeaderDictionary headers)
{
    return keys.Intersect(headers.Keys)
        .Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(k,headers[k]))
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
}
```

Test Case :

```
var list = new List<string>{
    "Content-tyb3",  // non-exist
    "Cookie",        
    "Accept-Language",
    "Program",      // non-exist
};
var headers = GetHeaderValues(list,Request.Headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join your keys with the headers, then turn that result in a dictionary like so, however the value may not be a single string. In this solution I've called ToString() on the StringValue object, which might not be what you want, but it's what your method signature shows:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> GetHeaderValues(
    IReadOnlyList<string> keys, IHeaderDictionary headers)
{
    return headers
    .Join(keys, h => h.Key, k => k, (h, k) => h)
    .ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => h.Value.ToString());
}
```